# Pandas Cummulative Sum and Multiple Group By

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a table which has Per Day, Per State, Per County Counts

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3], 'state': ['CA','CA','IN','IN','CA','CA','IN','IN','TX','CA'], 'County':['San Diego','SFO','Monroe','Kent','San Diego','SFO','Monroe','Hous','Mazs','San Diego'], 'count':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4]})
```

[image]

I want to convert it to
[image]

I tried it like this

```
data.groupby(['DATE','State','County'])['count'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
```

and I dont get the cummulative sum...I get the initial table as results

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
data['new'] = data.groupby(['State','County'])['count'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Excellent.. Thank you.. May I please know Why it wont work if I add Date 
ata['new'] = data.groupby(['Date','State','County'])['count'].cumsum()

Comment: @ChaitanyaPatil you have unique date for each per State and County so that dose not work , since one group only have one row. not value sumed